# Typing inverted question / exclamation marks in Swiftkey on iPhone

Tags: iphone, swiftkey

Is it possible to enter these characters? (For Spanish text)

I could not find them, and I'm sure I'm using the Spanish QWERTY keyboard in SwiftKey (with the ñ)

Comment: On the built in keyboard, I tap and hold the "!" to see an option for "¡". Does that work for you?

Comment: `alt/option + !` for ¡ and `alt/option + shift + ?` for ¿ . Is this what you're looking for ?

Comment: @bassplayer7 yes, it does. It would be nice to have that in SwiftKey's "shortcut" punctuation key, though.

Comment: @maetsoh iPhone+SwiftKey, not OSX.

Comment: oh sorry then holding the keys ! and ? is what you're looking for

Answer (score 1):

As @bassplayer7 suggested, I need to hold the `!` in the symbols page. I was expecting to have this in the `!@#,.?` key, like in Android.

Comment: the iOS keyboard layout is different from Android's

Comment: @maetsoh and worse.

Comment: @Alex.S you would if you were using the Spanish keyboard.

Comment: Yes, I have already tried it :)

Comment: @Alex.S I don't have my Android phone anymore; otherwise I'd show you a screenshot :-). But it was definitely there (to the left of the popup)

Comment: I wanted to say "yes, you are right. I tried the spanish layout and `¡` was here". Sorry for confusion :)

Comment: @Alex.S ah. No worries :-)